Is it risky to travel by "self-transfer"?
I am short of money.
I am planning to purchase a ticket with the "self-transfer" option.
Is it risky?
Do I get sufficient time for collecting my baggaes

This is impossible to answer.  It will depend on the airport, the amount of time between your flight, the weather on the day, and a whole bunch of other things.

If you miss the second flight, do you have enough money to buy a new ticket on the spot for the same day, (often way more expensive)?

There’s a very good summary of the risks of self-transfer in the answer to this question

Maybe a more fruitful way to frame the question are “What are the risks of self-transfer?”

It depends on a lot of factors. Think about worst case scenario (time, cost, missed opportunities). On some travels it my be ok, on other no (intercontinental self transfer is often bad, but for regular business travels [so light travel, and knowing the airport]))

It is inherently more risky than a "real" connection, for a lot of reasons:

You need a lot more time

If you have checked luggage, you need to retrieve them and check them in again.
If you have to go through check-in/baggage drop (either because you have checked luggage, or because you can't check-in online or on your mobile, or because you need to go through extra checks, for instance), you need to do so before the check-in deadline, which is often around one hour before departure. Remember that in many places check-in/bag drop is shared for many flights, and there can be long queues. See below for what happens if you don't (there's no "sterile transit", everybody exits the secure area even if they have a connection).
Depending on the combination of flights and the airport, you may need to go through passport control (in and/or out), which can take a lot of time in some places. In some places, this will be required only if you need to go through check-in. In others you will have to do this even if you don't.
You may have to go through general security, which, again, may take a lot of time (for "real" connections there are usually dedicated transfer security checkpoints which are generally less busy and a lot faster).
It is less likely that both your flights use the same terminal. In some airports terminals can be a loooong way apart.
You need more buffer (see below).

Note that even if you don't have checked luggage, you may need to go through check-in and/or passport control and/or security.

You may need more paperwork

If the transit airport is not in the same country (or union like the Schengen Area) as either the origin or destination, you may need a visa, or a different type of visa. Remember that many airlines will consider that your transit airport is not a transit, but your final destination. You must have the required paperwork to enter the transit airport country.


You are on your own

One of the two flights is rescheduled and the connection is no longer possible? You are on your own to change one of the flights (at a cost).

One of the two flights is cancelled (in advance or at the last minute)? You are on your own to find a new flight or route (at a cost).

The first flight is delayed and you miss the second flight? You are on your own to find a new flight (at a cost).

There are other delays (passport control queue longer than usual, security longer than usual...) and you miss the second flight? You are on your own to find a new flight (at a cost).


Each of the airlines does not care about your other flight. For them, they're bringing you from point A to point B. Whether you arrive at A or depart from B by foot, car, train, bus, or another flight is the same for them: not their problem.
Remember that "missing the flight" means "not having checked-in/dropped bags before the deadline" (often one hour before departure) or "not reaching the gate before the deadline" (often about 20 minutes before departure).
Remember also that if you need to rebook, prices usually go higher as you get closer to the date. Flights for the same day or the next day can be a lot more expensive than flights booked a month or two in advance.
Also note that the next available flight may not be the same day. It may be the next day, or even later. You would need to pay yourself for any hotels, meals, transfers, etc. while you wait.
It's also worth remembering that not all airports are open 24/7. If you need to wait for a flight the next day, you may not be able to just camp out at the airport. Also, in many cases you can't actually check-in earlier than 3-4 hours before the flight. So if you have to wait, you probably have to do so landside (the "public" side of the airport, outside security), or out of the airport if it doesn't remain open overnight.


For all these reasons, most people consider that the minimum connection time should be at least 4 hours. However:

It does not guarantee anything. If your incoming flight is delayed by 3 hours and you have checked baggage you will still miss your second flight.
If the second flight is expensive, or infrequent, or often full, or you are travelling during a busy period, or during a period known for bad weather (so the extra cost and delay if you miss it and need to rebook is significant), then adding more time is a good idea. Ideally an overnight stay.
If you are not travelling alone, and especially if you travelling with kids or elderly/frail people, think of the consequences of having to wait for hour or days if anything goes badly.

In the end, it's up to you to evaluate the risk:

The probability there could be a problem
The extra cost and inconvenience if there is one

Note that some sites sell self-transfers, and supposedly have a "guarantee". Those guarantees are often very limited (for instance some will not pay more than the original cost of the missed flight!), subject to a lot of conditions, and may be unpractical. I wouldn't rely too much on them.
Some travel insurance policies may help (you do have travel insurance, right?), but this is extremely variable, may again come with a lot of limitations and conditions. Read the fine print.
